# How to assign a workflow when author tries to delete anything from Dam asset in AEM?

Tags: workflow, aem

I have a requirement where a workflow asking for approval for deletion should be triggered when author tries to delete any item from DAM asset, I tried using the workflow launcher but it is triggered after the item is deleted and an error pops up in the inbox saying **"The resource used to start this instance does not exist"**.

Answer (score 0):

"The resource used to start this instance does not exist" just means you are calling a non-existing function, or there is a problem with the workflow you are calling.

I would update your author permissions in AEM.  Prevent the authors from having the ability to delete content from /content/dam, only give them read and create access.  Then communicate to all your authors that if they want to delete a image, they will need to use the following workflow "".

The newly created workflow will create a ticket and assign it to the proper channels to approve the deletion request.

Comment: ok here's an update, what we need here is to trigger a workflow if author clicks on "delete" option in DAM asset. Any ideas on how we can call a workflow on a click of a button?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770058/how-to-take-an-action-on-a-deleted-asset-in-adobe-experience-manager to see if that helps.