# How to read a JCR Node's properties BEFORE it's deleted in Adobe Experience Manager?

Tags: adobe, workflow, aem, jcr

I need to audit properties of a JCR Node before the OTB deleted workflow physically deletes the node.

AEM provides a few ways to listen to deleted events. I've tried both the EventListener and a ResourceChangeListner. Both scenarios alert my code when a delete is triggered. However, I receive a "does not exist" when performing a session.getNode on the onChange path.

To validate I'm using the correct session/user/etc, I tested that I **AM** able to retrieve the node's parent. So, this proves I have the correct permissions and my listener is being informed after the node is already gone. Also, I have seen this work at least once so this is, obviously, a race condition. Sometimes I am alerted before the node is gone sometimes I am not.

So, how do I ***guarantee*** my code will be called **before** the JCR Node is actually gone?

Before you reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770058), I am applying solutions #2 and #3. Both have the same race condition result. #1 doesn't describe how to tie into the existing OTB AEM 'delete' 'workflow', is that possible?

Comment: I am not 100% sure ... but you might want to check out the Observation JCR API: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/12_Observation.html.If that does not help: copy the the OTB workflow, disabled the OTB workflow launcher, create your own workflow and enable it via launcher and add your requirements there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, yes it is possible and in my opinion the easiest way.
See [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/developing/extending-aem/extending-workflows/workflows-models.html) how to extend Workflows.
And see [here in the official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/developing/extending-aem/extending-workflows/workflows-program-interaction.html) how to interact with workflows programmatically.

If you need to read the data on specific nodes, you could also write your own workflow and apply it on those nodes with a workflow launcher. See [this](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/administering/operations/workflows-starting.html)